# gitflow with two development environments

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

Is there a recommended approach to when working with GitFlow to accommodate multiple dev environments as well as a production environment?

A project I'm working on has to maintain a production site along with two development environments.

The first dev environment reflects any changes that relate the the current live environment - these are mostly minor changes.

The second dev environment contains more significant changes and updates as part of a more long term project.

All three environments are set up  with local and remote hosting to cover long term development, testing/sign off and live. As an aside I'm also rolling out pipelines to build test and deploy each branch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly part of GitFlow, I "think" what you are describing is covered with the concept of Support Branches.  These are discussed here:

http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/#support-branches

This would allow you to maintain both scenarios that you describe.  i.e. continue to use your develop branch for the large ticket items, and update a support branch with the minor changes, allowing you to push out changes quickly.